# Bit Manipulation Syntax Question Java

Tags: java

```
checker |= (1 << val);
```

What does the |= do?

The 1 << val shifts the bits to the left which increases the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same as `checker = checker | (1 << val)`, just like `checker += val` is the same as `checker = checker + val`.

`|` means logical OR, i.e. if either source value has a bit set, it will be set in the target.

Answer (score 5):

This code is equivalent to

checker = checker | (1 << val)

Here, `|` is the bitwise OR operator, which takes in two numbers and returns a new number with 1 bits set anywhere that either input number has a one bit set.  The `|=` you're seeing is the "bitwise OR with assignment," which is like `+=` or `*=` but with `|`.